# HVAC Air returns help. Please

Tags: hvac

[image: Bedroom air return]
I am having problem with my bedroom staying as cool as the rest of the house. I have just moved in and I looked at the HVAC in the garage and I could not find where the filter is.  The paper work that came with the system is basically the warranty  and schematics. So I have one larger return, maybe 2’ x 2’ in the main living area. I opened it and there is a filter.  It is brand new. I have another air intake in one of the bedrooms. I opened it and the picture attached is what is there. Is that a plug? Why is it there? Could this be causing that bedroom to not cool down? 
Thanks in advance...

---

[image: Vent and I take in bedroom]

Also the vent above the door is above every door in the house but the bathroom. I have never seen this before either. It isn’t a register. It’s just a vent. The registers are all in the ceiling. I suppose that might be why the vents are above the door?? Help circulate the air? Because the intakes I have in The house have filters am I to assume there are no filters at the main unit in the garage?

Comment: Does the bedroom cool better if you leave the door blocked open about 6 inches?  Is there any draft of air through that doorway when the A/C is on?    If the door swings into the bedroom, does it close extra-easy/auto-close when the air is on, or if it swings out, is it harder to close?

Comment: Yes I did notice leaving the door open the room cools better. I didn’t notice a change while using the door. The specific return is on the ceiling about 6” from the door frame. Right now it is just open. A big 12” x 12” square leading into the duct work. I took the plate off and took the dirty filter out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the air return in the bed room is blanked off it will reduce the flow in the bedroom. If there are no filters at the furnace you will need one at the intake once the plate is removed. Why would someone blank off an intake? It may have been to reduce noise and or if the room was two warm or cold when the system was running for central heat/AC.

Comment: Thank you for the response Ed Beal.  I took off the plate and there was a filter in there. Very dirty. So I am going to go pick up a 12 x 12 filter to replace the old one. Hopefully that will allow more cool air into the room.